# python creating a list of dictionaries which is separated by minute per element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

hey guys I have a list of dictionaries that have timestamps which I want to separate by minute in each iteration.

So currently my dictionary looks like this :

```
{
    "taco.tuesday": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:18:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:19:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:20:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:21:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:22:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        }
    ],
    "macoroni.mondays": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:18:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:19:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:20:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:21:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:22:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        }
    ],
    "salmon.sundays": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:18:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:19:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:20:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:21:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:22:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        }
    ],
    "whatever.wednesday": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:18:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:19:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:20:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:21:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-11 02:22:00-05:00",
            "cost": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

But what I  want is my results to look like this for each minute  :

```
[{
    "taco.tuesday": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:38:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "macoroni.mondays": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:38:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "salmon.sundays": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:38:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "whatever.wednesday": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:38:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    }
}],

[{
    "taco.tuesday": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:39:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "macoroni.mondays": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:39:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "salmon.sundays": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:39:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "whatever.wednesday": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:39:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    }
}],

[{
    "taco.tuesday": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:40:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "macoroni.mondays": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:40:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "salmon.sundays": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:40:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    },
    "whatever.wednesday": {
        "timestamp": "2021-02-11 01:40:00-05:00",
        "cost": 0
    }
}]
```

here is what I have done so far to get the results I wanted:

```
e = defaultdict(dict)
for i in range(len(ts_results)):
    for key, value in tables.items():
        e[key]['timesamp'] = str(ts_results[i])
        e[key]['cost'] = 0
```

what is the best way of achieving this  solution?

Comment: You may find functions in the `itertools` library useful.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for responding. So far I have currently tried turning the list into a dict but that wasnt the solution as it removes all my other timestamps except the last minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on Ángel Igualada's answer, but corrects how he creates the nested dictionaries.

```
dict_by_time = {}
# for over your dict (called d here)
for k,v in d.items(): 
    for record in v:
        t = record["timestamp"]
        d = dict_by_time.get(t, {})
        d[k] = record
        dict_by_time[t] = d

result = list(dict_by_time.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using additional libraries, you could do something like:

```py
dict_by_time = {}
# for over your dict (called d here)
dict_by_time = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    for record in v:
        t = record["timestamp"]
        if t not in dict_by_time:
            dict_by_time[t] = {}
        dict_by_time[t].update({k:record})
```

This will give you a dict indexed by the timestamp string, if you want only the values, you can use:

```py
list(dict_by_time.values())
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired result. Each element of `dict_by_time` is a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary keyed by nicknames.

Comment: You're right, i missed that part, It should be ok now